# All the [movement] has ceased

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

The [movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/movement) tag currently has <s>354</s> <s>824</s> 957 questions from all over the tag spectrum.

There's no clear direction in which these questions go, but here's some of the questions topics I see there:

- Animations, some questions ask about moving items across the screen.
- Files, some questions ask about moving files on the disk.
- Physical position, some ask about movement of a device in the real world.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring -  Q: +41/0. A1 (saying Yes): +8/0, A2 (saying Yes): +12/0, A3 (saying Yes): +3/0

Comment: Note: This is an almost large tag, as it has 958 questions. However, as it is still lesser than 1000, we would be going through the entire burnination process, even if it crosses 1000 at the end of featuring.

Comment: It would be better to use plain language to describe your proposal instead of *cutsie* non-words like `"burninate"`. That detracts from the professional administration of the site.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin, it has been the accepted word since a very long time. See [What does it mean to burninate a tag?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/120640/). (Related [Change the name of burninate](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/282927/change-the-name-of-burninate))

Comment: It is just out of place on a technical site. I'm not badgering you, but as part of the community and a professional engineer and attorney for over 20 years, that use of language is simply wrong. There are no dragons that are magically going to descend and reduce the `[movement]` tag to ashes. `"remove"` is all that is required.

Comment: @DavidC.Rankin - It is Stack Overflow's legalese name for the process of editing posts, editing tag wikis, creating synonyms, changing tag lists, and in some cases restricting tag use by blacklisting it. Surely, as an attorney for over 20 years, it make sense to you to use jargon to describe complex processes. Oh, and there are dragons, just to clear that up.

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring - Q: +98/-1 A1 (saying Yes): +20/0, A2 (saying Yes): +40/0, A3 (saying Yes): +9/0. The community has voted in favor of burnination.

Comment: For some reason this tag isn't blacklisted even if it says **DO NOT USE**

Answer (score 45):

Someone really needs to get this ball moving.

Even though the Tag wiki says its an ambigous Tag (" DO NOT USE - ambiguous ") this tag is still beeing used regularly. The last question on it was yesterday. And the total number of questions in [movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/movement) has climbed to [824](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/movement)(!) Questions from the mere 354 when this request was created.

I suggest a concerted effort to burn this tag off the Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 22):

Agree to reorganize and burn.

I posted some additional suggestions in the tag wiki. Copied here for convenience:

- sprites and animation (movement of graphics) [sprites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sprites) [animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animation)
- phone or other accelerometers (detecting movement) [accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accelerometer)
- path finding algorithms [path-finding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/path-finding)
- movement of objects [physics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/physics)
- moving files, eg. on disk [file-move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-move)

Comment: very good; but we also need data-movement or memory-movement (maybe no questions yet but it does come up ...)

Comment: Nice list.  As to `movement` -- kill it with fire.

Answer (score 15):

[movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/movement) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

---

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

Taken from the other answer, feel free to add to this.

- sprites and animation (movement of graphics) [sprites](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/sprites) [animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/animation)
- phone or other accelerometers (detecting movement) [accelerometer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/accelerometer)
- path finding algorithms [path-finding](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/path-finding)
- movement of **game** objects [game-physics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/game-physics)
- movement of objects [physics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/physics)
- moving files, eg. on disk [file-move](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/file-move)

## Progress:

The [movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/movement) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=movement),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmovement%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmovement%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- <s>[Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmovement%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)</s> 0 posts
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bmovement%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## [Track progress of the burnination!](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176535/burnination-progress-for-the-movement-tag)

[image]

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/movement) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/movement) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions that still remain with the [movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/movement) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.

Answer (score 10):

The tag now has the short description,

> DO NOT USE - ambiguous

It is arguably overdue for removal, but still sees use by new users, as well as users who do not read tag descriptions (or this meta) before tagging their questions.

The number of uses of [movement](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/movement) is now up to 838.

Comment: This tag should be **blacklisted** as well.