# Change the name of "Burninate"

Tags: discussion, burninate-system

I don't like the word.  It looks too much like "Urinate".  I wish that didn't appear on my screen on many of my visits to SO.  Can we come up with a different name for this?

Comment: Do you have a suggested new name to replace urnina... I mean burninate?

Comment: I don't know; how about "burn"?

Comment: Trogdor does not urinate on the countryside.

Comment: I'd say this would be a losing battle. [Burninate has been around far too long to change now.](http://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101417/164200)

Comment: Just to check: you *are* aware that there is a [meme](http://knowyourmeme.com/memes/trogdor) behind the name, right?

Comment: @WilliamJockusch Burn would be far too boring, if you can suggest something absolutely mind-blowing, then possibly. But you'd have to really convince everyone that Burninate needs to be replaced.

Comment: @WilliamJockusch "Burn" ain't good enough. "Burninate" has the feel of being an [intensive form](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intensive_word_form) of "burn". I know it is a made up word but that it happens to look like it *could* be an actual intensive form of burn is quite nice.

Comment: http://i.stack.imgur.com/LPbFu.jpg

Comment: If the word ur...burninate is a serious problem for you, may I suggest writing a userscript to change **BURNINATE** -> **URINATE** (or another word of your choosing)?

Comment: Piss on that suggestion.

Comment: Better to be pissed off than pissed on

Comment: Can't win 'em all, I guess

Comment: @Compass - nor the `[peoples]` nor the `[thatched-roof-cottages]`

Comment: If we want to stick with memes, why not `accidentally`?

Comment: Let's burinate "burinate"! A good new name would be "discard". "Discard the [movement] tag" sounds good

Comment: What is seen cannot be unseen

Comment: Fun thing is, when I type "burninate", Chrome suggests "urinate" word instead.

Answer (score 170):

I agree that "burninate" looks too much like "urinate." We need a new term for when we want to **massively terminate** a tag. I suggest we get rid of the offensive "burninate" and use **massternate** henceforth.

Comment: *:waves hand:* *ohhyou.png*

Comment: I agree this new suggestion is just fool-proof, not like *burninate*!

Comment: Lets make this retroactive and burninate Burninate in favor of Massternate.

Comment: I once saw a custom license plate and thought it said EMBRYO when it actually said FORMYBRO.  Funny thing is, the person in the car with me at first thought it said EMBRYO too

Comment: But what will the dragon shoot for massively terminated tags?

Comment: Darn, I laughed. I guess I just lost the game.

Comment: @TravisJ: T-1000s.

Comment: @TravisJ Streams of urine, obviously. ;)

Comment: @user4480584 http://www.quickmeme.com/img/b6/b6509c42a9c5080a725f2753a4886953d79bd8266d8ebb5b4e8f5756eeba9ea1.jpg

Comment: Well well, I've been reading it as *burnitate* for all those years...

Answer (score 72):

Let's keep Burninate

- It doesn't look at all like urinate to me. Maybe you need to use a different font
- One of my heroes, Trogdor, demonstrated perfect burnination - use of burninate here is a direct homage
- Burninate describes very well what we do - equivalent to razing to the ground and sowing with salt

Burninate Burninate Burninate

[image]

Comment: Except sometimes we don't sow enough salt and it comes back. So maybe we should change it to "burnsaltinate", just to remind us about the salt part.

Comment: That sounds like a chemical you add to a fish tank to reduce algae..maybe

Comment: @Undo - case in point:  how many times has the [application] tag been burninated only to pop back up again?

Comment: @LittleBobbyTables - I don't think that would happen with Bill's massternate suggestion.

Comment: @TravisJ Just show it some hot network questions and give it some time.