# Burninate [zeroes]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request

The tag [zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zeroes) has questions with a variety of languages and seems to be very unfocused.

It has questions ranging from how to remove a set of zeroes from a string using [regular expressions](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_expression), to [MySQL](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MySQL) padding questions, and doesn't seem to be adding anything to the site.

Comment: [Urinate zeroes?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/282927/change-the-name-of-burninate) That doesn't make sen... oh, wait!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

23 questions (when I started burning) tagged [zeroes](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/zeroes) burninated.