# The [hdd] tag is in the process of being cleaned

Tags: discussion, status-completed, burninate-request, clean-up

*The Phase #2 of the burnination process described here, is completed and it has been decided that the tag should NOT be removed from the system. The tag is now in the process of being cleaned up. Please see the answer below to keep track of progress*

---

I noticed the [hdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdd) tag today, and it seems to be a bastion for mis-tagged and off-topic questions. Nearly every question belonged on Super User or Server Fault, and for the remainder it seemed to be a totally superfluous tag. I'm having a hard time thinking of any programming question which would benefit from this tag.

Can we burninate it?

Comment: Quite a cesspool. Let's clean it up.

Comment: [ssd] looks like it is in the same shape.  But I think it should stay with clean up and [hdd] should probably be merged into [storage].

Comment: What about this "question"? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/782053/get-hdd-and-not-volume-serial-number-on-vista-ultimate-64-bit

Comment: @ColeJohnson Looks like a general hardware/software question to me.

Comment: Don't forget that *dd can also be a design paradigm (tdd for test driven development, bdd for behavior driven, etc). I would hate to lock people out of future tags that they may actually have a need to use.

Comment: There is also the very ambiguous [drive](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drive) tag.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring, Q: +102/-4, Answer asking to cleanup: +35/-3, Answer asking to rename/broaden the tag: +6/-1

Comment: Format the Hard-Disk-Drive..

Comment: This question and the first 2 answers appear to have been dormant for 3 years before featuring.  Are any of the stats given in the first answer meaningful any more?

Comment: If you need help destroying hard drives safely, [Lifehacks](https://lifehacks.stackexchange.com/questions/11777/how-can-i-safely-destroy-a-hard-disk) has some tips :P

Comment: Follow-up question? When do we care about the difference between a rotating head disk and a solid state disk?

Comment: Found this: [My Xcode installation is taking up loads of space; how to reduce space used by simulators?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31475782/my-xcode-installation-is-taking-up-loads-of-space-how-to-reduce-space-used-by-s) which arguably should be migrated to AskDifferent or ServerFault

Comment: @Kara: almost all [666 questions in '[drive]'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drive) ironically seem to be about Google Drive, although not necessarily about its API ([tag:google-drive-sdk]). Should we rename [tag:drive] -> [google-drive] ?

Comment: could we get rid of the "burninate" tag? it's from mostly US centric awesome website, but can be really confusing for non-native english speakers. It's also unclear what "burninate" even means in these discussions.....

Comment: @kebno see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/282927/change-the-name-of-burninate?noredirect=1&lq=1 and https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/318358/stop-using-burninate?noredirect=1&lq=1 and up till now the consensus seems to be: Let's leep that name.

Comment: While I'm fine with burninating it, it should be noted that this is a valid programming topic for a variety of reasons--not all of us program at the user level all the time.

Comment: hate driven development?

Comment: @kebno I agree in principle but it seems to be an ingrained part of the culture now...

Comment: I'll leave this up for one more day, to wait for any further arguments. It seems to be very clear about not burninating the tag, but just to clean up.

Comment: Next up: should we burn [tag:cd-rom]? And for once nobody can come up with a punnier burninate title than that!

Comment: @kebno wouldn't any alternative be just as confusing, if not more?

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +188/-12. Answers asking for cleanup: +89/-6, +15/0 Answer asking for rename +44/-5. Looks like the community is in favour of a clean-up, hence the burnination request is declined. Let's clean up the tag!

Comment: @AndrewGrimm what do you think?

Comment: @BhargavRao Are the related tags listed [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/286220/4032703) part of the "official" clean-up effort?

Comment: @EJoshuaS just one at a time, the progress answer is what you need to be tracking. Feel free to create meta posts asking for the cleanup of the others.

Comment: @BhargavRao I went ahead and had SOCVR delete the closed questions out of the tag. If you will go ahead and synonym [hdd] to [hard-drive] this will be totally complete

Comment: Thanks for that @Machavity, I hadn't forgotten about this (I've got it pinned on my desktop), but been a bit too busy with exams. I'll get the synonym done today evening.

Answer (score 84):

[hdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdd) **really needs a clean up**, and you might as well handle some related tags while you are at it.

- [hard-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive) is a synonym of [hdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdd)
- [ssd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssd) also a drive, same problem
- [fdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fdd) has four questions and can be burninated as it's ambiguous
- [floppy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floppy) similar problems to [hdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdd)

Most of the questions in these tags are either negatively scored or closed. In all of the tags, over 50% of the questions are <0 or closed.

- [hdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdd) [92/133 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhdd%5D+score%3A0..+closed%3Ano)
- [hard-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive) [295/471 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhard-drive%5D+score%3A0..+closed%3Ano)
- [ssd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssd) [103/141 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssd%5D+score%3A0..+closed%3Ano)
- [floppy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floppy) [25/40 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bfloppy%5D+score%3A0..+closed%3Ano)

After they are cleaned up, and only on-topic questions remain (if there are any), it is *at that point* that we should consider possible next options

- Make all of the tags a synonym of [storage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storage) or [storage-devices](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/storage-devices)
- Only clean up the duplicate tags

  - [hdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdd) should be made a synonym of [hard-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive)
  - [floppy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floppy) should be renamed to [floppy-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floppy-drive)
  - [status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed): [fdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/fdd) should be burninated

Comment: I am not convinced. There are non-trivial differences among the various types of storage. One certainly *can* be an expert in programming tape systems, or dealing with the special needs of SSDs, or making music with floppy drives.

Comment: @dfeuer Sarcasm aside, there are a whopping total of [38 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bssd%5D+score%3A0+closed%3Ano) tagged [tag:ssd] that are not closed and have a score of zero or above. That's 38 questions out of 141 tagged, and I'm not even convinced that all of those are on-topic.

Comment: Have you tried defragmenting the hdd? What I wanted to drop in, i would more go with a tag like storage medium instead of storage. Storage can mean multiple things and storage medium is more specific to certain questions, whilst storage in general can apply to the way a mysql database stores itself.

Comment: Your SO Q&A metrics are too unreliable, tentative to base assertions on. All of those questions could be edited, reviewed, and answered tomorrow. The number of questions tagged could triple by tomorrow, respectfully.

Comment: Also,  `hard` and `floppy` are both properties of `disk-drives`; an `optical-disk-storage-device` is synonmous with `hdd` **as we currently know it** (which is in itself, a tentative phrase). To that point, Solid State Drives are not disk drives. They do not use the samee underline mechanics to read, write, and persist data. They bring a completely different set of concerns. Additionally, all of these are considered `storage-devices` (storages?)

Comment: @BrettCaswell If/when the tags are cleaned up, the numbers will change. That's going to happen naturally, over time, and I wouldn't necessarily call them unreliable because of that.

Comment: As far as deciding what the tags will look like, I _really think we need to wait_ and see what the landscape looks like after the off-topic questions are cleaned out.

Comment: unreliable in argumentative sense, because they are in a tentative state.. someone may very well reword every question as others address and answer each. They may even do it because of this posting.. Then the opposite arguementative point (based on those assertions) would become valid.. i.e. questions with those tags tend to lead to positive questions, answers, and activity.

Comment: -1 for the [tag:floppy] part: most are about floppy disks rather than drives (reading, formatting etc). Besides, that topic is mostly the domain of [retrocomputing.se] now, so it doesn't make much sense to microcategorize here.

Comment: maybe `block-storage` for such devices would be a good tag that can have useful programming questions

Answer (score 41):

The type of medium used for the conceptual purpose of storage **CAN** lend itself to the context of the question and answer. Even if the question itself is just interfacing with the software driver.

> I'm having a hard time thinking of any programming question which would benefit from this tag.

how about firmware, kernel-level programming, software device drivers, device and driver emulators..

> ... seems to be a bastion for mis-tagged and off-topic questions. ...
>
> Can we burninate it

No, the misused, off-topic instances you've encounter (in memory, and without citing) have no regard to those who would provide the tag on-topic and appropriately (past, present, and **future**). If you subscribe or address questions with `hdd`, that are off-topic and misused - remove them. That's the appropriate action here.

If `hdd` seems to specific, make it generic: `disk-drive`..

Comment: Besides the low level stuff there may well be other (probably performance related) programming questions. E.g. you could do I/O heavy processing in parallel on SSD but sequential on HDD to get the best time to completion.

Comment: @AVee, I agree.. As an application, Samsung's **Rapid Mode** feature comes to mind.

Comment: Another distinction between HDDs and SSDs is how data deletion and overwriting works. This is important for things like secure wiping and data recovery.

Answer (score 16):

Having done a lot of the recent closures on [hdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdd) and [ssd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssd), a lot of the on-topic questions could be retagged to [disk-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disk-access), as it suggests programming as opposed to the ambiguous ones we have now

While Brett makes a decent **generic** argument for [ssd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssd), the reality is too many people are asking questions about *drive speed* or *hardware implementation*, which isn't on-topic (i.e. Why isn't my DB faster on SSD?)

We have too many synonyms for all this as well

- [hdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdd)
- [ssd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/ssd)
- [floppy](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/floppy)
- [hard-drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hard-drive)
- [disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disk)
- [drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drive)
- [on-disk](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/on-disk)

We should also synonym [diskusage](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/diskusage) to [disk-access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/disk-access)

Comment: Burn the `disk` !

Comment: [tag:drive] has 666 questions! It's probably already on fire

Comment: @Machavity I'm most concerned about how many of the questions tagged [drive](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/drive) are actually about Google drive

Comment: @NickA Burnination involves cleaning those up

Comment: "a lot of the on-topic questions could be retagged to disk-access" could you offer examples of questions that would benefit from having those tags?

Comment: Disk usage and disk access are two separate entities (but disk usage is misused a bit). Disk usage is about the load on a disk (e.g. how can I measure disk usage in this testing environment/how can I reduce disk usage for this operation). Disk access is just about accessing the disk.

Answer (score 9):

## Progress:

The [hdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdd) tag is in the process of being cleaned. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=hdd),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value).

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhdd%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhdd%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhdd%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bhdd%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [hdd](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/hdd) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.

Comment: We're down to 23 open questions. I would go ahead and delete the closed and synonym this to [hard-drive]

Comment: Good one @Machavity, and then lets start a clean-up effort on that tag as well.

Answer (score -6):

Just add [ssd] they are dramatically different devices. And keep [hdd] it does it's job. Later the dust will settle and it might become useful.

Answer (score -9):

I think the tag should be kept. Mainly because I think that there are practical differences between how a hard disk drive and solid state drive behave in certain circumstances. As others have mentioned low level access is one such circumstance.

Another circumstance is how deleted data behaves. SSDs will typically try to avoid writing to areas that have already been written to, even if the data is deleted. This has important consequences for things like secure deleting of data.

Also, HDDs and SSDs typically fail in different ways.

In my opinion we should keep distinct tags for HDDs and SSDs.

Comment: I think nobody is arguing those are different types of disks with different characteristics. If you want to make a case of keeping the tags you need to bring in arguments how they help finding questions that address a specific programming problem encountered by developers when writing software. Assuming most HDD's  and SDD's sit behind an abstraction layer their differences doesn't matter from a developer point of view. And that limited scope kind of surpasses the need to differentiate between hdd and sdd or hdd's in general.

Comment: @rene That is an erroneous assumption in the field of operating systems, a tag that has over 9000 questions. What you are doing here is exploiting the misuse of a system to justify its destruction. Fix the users, not the tag. By percussive maintenance if necessary.

Comment: Okay, can you elaborate in your answer what the percussive maintenance should look like so the users who need to be fixed have something to refer to?

Comment: If you can produce a practical programming case where we need these tags, we're more than happy to entertain keeping them. But so far this answer (and the other defending) are offering hypotheticals

Comment: @rene For very low level programming (i.e. firmware (production/testing), potentially driver level), SSDs and HDDs are dramatically different. However, the misuse of these tags significantly overwhelms any questions which might appropriately fit into such categories. Perhaps what we need is something more specific—maybe [tag:hdd-firmware] and/or [tag:ssd-firmware]—for those few questions which actually fit?