# Stop using [burninate]

Tags: discussion, tags

I have a feeling that this will go over like a lead balloon, but I have to ask!  The term "burninate" is both childish and exclusionary!  There is no such word!  It only means something to a small cadre of meta.SO elitist nerds.  It is childish and pointless.  To those meta.SO users whose first language is not English, it is yet another pointless idiom which they have to decipher.  To those meta.SO users whose first language is English, it is yet another pointless idiom which they have to decipher.

I apologize if this sounds like a "rant".  I do not mean it to be .  I just think a site as extraordinarily popular, and useful, as SO should conduct itself with a bit more decorum.  This site is no longer a secret little club for a few geeks.  This is worldwide!  And, have you forgotten that [We Hate Fun](https://goo.gl/YqFIIJ)

> On Stack Overflow, contrary to popular opinion, we don't hate fun. But
>   only a certain amount of fun will be tolerated, and always with
>   steely, businesslike frowns. :)

The term "burninate" has had its run.  It's not "fun" anymore.  It's embarrassing.

Comment: @vaultah:  I wouldn't call the posts duplicates.  The post you reference doesn't like "burninate" because it sounds too much like "urinate".  I don't like "burninate" because it is infantile.

Comment: Tempted to change the title to "Burninate [burninate]" or something...

Comment: @AlexanderO'Mara: As was I, but the madness has to end somewhere.  :)

Comment: In case anyone is curious about the origin of the word: [Origin/meaning of “burninate”](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/44273/origin-meaning-of-burninate)

Comment: So what would you suggest instead? "Destroy"?

Comment: @MartinSmith: Sure, "destroy" would work.  Perhaps a bit too strong though.  Any "real" word would work.  The first that comes to mind is "delete".  But "erase", "eliminate", "forbid", etc. are contenders.  Actually "forbid" is probably the best since the tag shall be forbidden.

Comment: If we switch to suggestion mode I would opt for [This tag should be `SOCVR-ed`](https://github.com/SO-Close-Vote-Reviewers/SOCVR-RoomInformation/blob/master/burnination.md)

Comment: @raven forbidden would imply black listing which is different from burnination.

Comment: If you hover over the tag or click on it you see a description of what it means and what it's used for. There is no confusion here. Also *"I apologize if this sounds like a "rant"* -> Yes. It does. Perhaps try using different *language* next time. It's not "meta.SO elitist nerds" who need to "conduct itself with a bit more decorum" here IMHO. Signed, meta.SO elitist nerd.

Comment: @MartinSmith: How is "black listing" different from "burnination"?

Comment: Nothing stops a burninated tag from reappearing. It's not blacklisted.

Comment: @Bart: Why remove a tag only to let it come back again?

Comment: Because it's usually sufficient to delete a tag. If it keeps reappearing it can be blacklisted. But that's usually not needed. And in light of the etymology provided (and if you really want to win Meta SO users over) you may want to revise your opener. If you don't want this to sound like a rant, don't write an actual rant.

Comment: It always annoyed me as well, probably because the origin of it was stupid.  It's not funny, it's not cool, and it really should be burninated.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker: The internet tends to make everyone sound angrier than they are.  Body language and voice inflection are lost.  If you are not the most careful of writers (I am not) you generally end up sounding like a douche bag (that would be me).  P.S.: love that user name, and I don't even know why!  However, I would suggest you munch on the carpet rather than smoking it!  Much less harmful to all parties involved!

Comment: I don't see this as a dupe. The answers there don't address the objections here (cliqueness, not a real word) because the question is different.

Comment: @MartinSmith fair enough, re-opened. You write an answer?

Comment: @raven I'm sorry, but while it's true that a lot of subtleties can be lost in internet communication, calling people "meta.SO elitist nerds" is not a subtle miscommunication. It is simply an insult. Full stop. Now, I don't really mind this as such (you're free to do so). I've been subjected to much worse. But I hope you will forgive me if I stop reading after this.

Comment: I don't mind burninate, since it has a very specific meaning and can't be confused with any other task. Delete, destroy, remove, block, blacklist etc could all refer to anything, deleting users/posts/wiki pages/whatever. Not to mention that they don't fit what a burnination actually is. I think it would be hard to find another word that even remotely describes the process equally well.

Comment: I think "burninate" is a portmanteau of "burn" and "exterminate", I don't think it's childish. Are you against all portmanteaus which don't appear in the dictionary, or only against "burninate"?

Comment: We don't hate fun on Meta.

Comment: How strange that "elitist nerd" is presented as a put-down.  Or treated as an insult for that matter.  If you are a programmer then you wear that label with pride.  A good one anyway.  So sure, sorry, we do have a lot of good programmers here.  The term was coined by Jeff Atwood, uncrowned King of the Nerds, and it stuck.  You'll have to deal with it.

Comment: To quote @CodyGray, We don't hate fun on Meta, squashing the jokes and funny words isn't the best idea. Showing more decorum is not applicable for the site dedicated to making the main site more "popular, and useful", so it's perfectly fine to be business-like on SO, that's the point. The poker room in the back is indeed meta. The party room is the chat room, if you were wondering. Could be worse, at least we don't use the [Salad](http://sopython.com/salad/) language, (no matter how much I want that...)

Comment: `The term "burninate" has had its run. It's not "fun" anymore. It's embarrassing.` says who?

Comment: Don't agree with OP's language and rant but I would +1000 upvote, as I too had to dig out the meaning of "burninate". The OP is absolutely correct when saying "it is yet another pointless idiom which they have to decipher". This tag should be replaced by "remove-tag", "delete-tag", "destroy-tag" or anything conveying more information than "burninate".

Answer (score 26):

Being one of the small cadre of meta.SO elitist nerds that is active in burninating tags that are brought up on meta, I'll share my view on it.

I don't think the term should be removed or changed despite it's possible childish, embarrassing, and pointless connotation for some users. One of the main reasons to have a somewhat awkward word is the relative complexity of the process involved. It isn't simply *destroy*, *remove*, *delete*, *eliminate*, or *forbid*.

Even before such a request can start there are [things to consider](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/239190/when-to-burninate/239191#239191) and for the larger lumps that needs more support the [SOCVR](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) room expanded the process proposed by [Shog9](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/307068/make-it-easier-to-prevent-new-questions-being-added-in-a-tag/307124#307124) a bit to [this beast](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/324070/what-is-the-process-for-tag-removal-burnination/324071#324071). Do notice that we already made one concession when a [burninate-request](/questions/tagged/burninate-request) gets featured (on main): the title gets edited to a neutral tone instead of the normal/mandatory [puns](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/295583/why-do-people-have-a-little-pun-with-their-retag-and-burninate-requests). See the stress that came over us [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/258571/revisions) as well in the comments.

When it is decided to take on a burnination activity, it needs coordination and effort from many hands to actually achieve its final goal. One example of that is the [legal cleanup](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/295218/578411). This shows that there are a lot of dimensions to be considered, again not easily replaced with a single word.

And in case users are really confused about what it is, the [tag wiki](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/tags/burninate-request/info) explains how it came into existence very well. Don't touch our [meme](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/101417).

**tl;dr** Although burninate might not be a word that fits a professional/enthusiastic setting it communicates the meaning for being a special combination of *destroy*, *delete*, *erase*, *eliminate*, *forbid*, and *cleanup* very well. The word can stay.

Comment: [Change the name of “Burninate”](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/282927/change-the-name-of-burninate)

Comment: @Deduplicator yeah, it was proposed as a duplicate and I dupe hammered  it in the end against that one but that was challenged.

Comment: Meh... the thing is that burnination isn't a word, but a process... btw, you forgot "cleanup".

Comment: No @Braiam I didn't forget *cleanup* because that word wasn't used by anyone in the comments under the question.

Comment: I meant in the "special combination" part.

Comment: You may have it @Braiam ;)

Comment: Agree with this answer - the term is jargon, of which SO has plenty. It serves a useful purpose, and we must only take care to ensure that it is documented well enough that folks who wish to participate constructively are able to do so.

Comment: @rene the link in "this beast" is broken o.o

Comment: @rene ok. that was fast.

Comment: @ItamarG3 I knew where the cheese moved to .. ;) .. thanks for reporting.