# We've achieved our [goal]

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

*This tag has been burninated. Please do not recreate it. If you need advice on which tag to use, see the answer below. If you see this tag reappearing, it may need to be blacklisted.*

---

I don't understand the *goal* behind the [goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goal).

The description of the tag says

> The [goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goal) tag has no usage guidance, can you [help us create it](https://stackoverflow.com/edit-tag-wiki/34034)?

So, the tag itself is ambiguous and has no guidelines of when the tag should be used. Most of the times, the tag is used in scenarios when OP thinks that I have this and my *goal* is ... and adds the tag to the question which is not necessary. Every question has a *goal* that OP wants to achieve.

At the moment, there are  <s>45</s>  66 questions, out of which  <s>30</s>  43 are used in conjunction with [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven). If we still need it with [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven) I'd suggest a new [maven-goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-goal) should be created with all the description and the questions should be retagged. As for the other questions, a few can be closed and for the others, [goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goal) can be removed.

[Does this tag even need to be burninated?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/239191/303632)

1. Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous? - **No**
2. Is the concept described even on-topic for the site? - **No**
3. Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post? - **No**
4. Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts? - **No**

The above **4 No** = **Yes to burninate**.

**Can we burninate it?**

Comment: If there is obvious consensus, I would be happy to take this on. Often these can be done easily by one person. The devil's in the details though.

Comment: Not sure if [tag:maven-goal] is warranted. Aren't goals an integral part of any maven scenario?

Comment: @ivan_pozdeev I thought that is needed because users using [tag:goal]. _Aren't goals an integral part of any maven scenario?_ Don't know about Java, but I can say if that is the case there is no need of adding [tag:goal] to those question, but users are still using that tag.

Comment: I don't think we should have a tag for the Lisp GOAL language.  If I recall, the GOAL compiler is proprietary and very few people even know the language besides Andy Gavin at Naughty Dog. The tag seems too generic to be of any value. I say burninate it.

Comment: Goals are used when working interactively with proof assistants and dependently typed functional languages.

Comment: Stats at the start of featuring: Q: +56/0; A1 (saying Yes) : +48/0, A2 (asking for disambiguation) : +14/-4

Comment: It seems that in the meantime there is something called a "Goal" in google analytics, not sure if it adds any value as a tag there.

Comment: What resurrected this request 2.5 years after the fact?

Comment: @DanNeely, long story short, I wanted to complete all the small ones soon. We've got a backlog of almost 4 years worth of burn-reqs and need some movement on those (talking of movement, [movement] was featured [5.5 years after the request](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/260218/4099593)). If you want the complete story [poke me in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/info/165597/trogdor).

Comment: @BhargavRao I don't think I need an extended back story, I'm glad though that something's being done about the orphaned requests.  I'd long since assumed that any tag rename/burn requests that didn't reach whatever the official do something threshold was after a few days/weeks had effectively failed and would never be fixed.

Comment: @DanNeely coincidently, I started a small discussion about orphaned burnination requests just a few hours ago https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/373599/4099593. We did have some 700 burn requests when we started out a few months back, and now we are down to 444.  Hopefully the community gets more involved in the burn requests and we manage to process them all in the next 3 years. :)

Comment: @Luuklag, I checked those posts, looks like there is already a [tag:goal-tracking] for those.

Comment: Would be good for that tag to have some usage guidance, @bhargavrao

Comment: Yup, @Luuklag, and also perhaps [retag these 9 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goal-tracking+-google-analytics*).

Comment: Stats at the end of featuring: Q: +91/0; A1 (saying Yes) : +72/0, A2 (asking for disambiguation) : +18/-5. The community has voted in favor of burnination.

Answer (score 71, accepted):

It is true that the notion of goal is widely used in Maven. In fact, so widely used that such a tag, [maven-goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-goal), would be completely unnecessary and redundant. [For those interested](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-lifecycle.html), goals are tasks that Maven plugins do during the build. And, basically, the whole Maven build revolves around declaring plugins, thus it adds no value.

There are currently  <s>8</s>  23 [goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goal) questions (out of the  <s>45</s>  66) that are not tagged with a Maven-related tag ([query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goal+-maven+-maven-2+-maven-3+-maven-plugin+-maven-assembly-plugin+-maven-release-plugin+-maven-surefire-plugin+-maven-jetty-plugin+-maven-archetype+-maven-dependency-plugin+-maven-jaxb2-plugin+-maven-tomcat-plugin+-maven-war-plugin+-maven-shade-plugin+-maven-antrun-plugin+-maven-site-plugin+-maven-failsafe-plugin+-maven-cargo+-maven-profiles+-maven-compiler-plugin)). Of those  <s>8</s>  23:

- 1 is about a programming language called [GOAL](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Oriented_Assembly_Lisp), or "Game Oriented Assembly Lisp". This tag could actually make sense for that but it is bound to be misused. A better name has to be found if there are other questions about this language, like [lisp-goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lisp-goal). ([How to stream program code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/4320166/1743880))
- 1 is about the Excel function "GoalSeek". Can be safely removed there. ([VBA GoalSeek Loop Issue](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34897910/1743880)).
- 3 are also tagged [prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/prolog). The tag adds no value. ([Finding the highest possible evaluation in prolog](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34631566/1743880), [How do I work with equations that are passed on in the goal/query of prolog?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9142989/1743880), [bagof/3 giving weird results](https://stackoverflow.com/q/34686786/1743880)).
- 3 are also tagged [piwik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piwik). The tag adds no value; the word "goal" is already in the title or in the body and that is why is what probably tagged this way. ([Piwik goals(checkout steps)](https://stackoverflow.com/q/14850654/1743880), [How to get Goal Conversion history from PIWIK](https://stackoverflow.com/q/5861438/1743880), [Tracking direct file downloads](https://stackoverflow.com/q/19675932/1743880)).

#### Conclusion:

[image: Let this tag burn in fire!]

Comment: Actually, I think you've made a pretty good case that [goal] is actually a thing.  That you don't personally feel that it's a useful thing in the context of maven is largely irrelevant.

Comment: @RobertHarvey Did I? For the programming language, a better tag has to be found that is more descriptive than [goal] because it'll be misused otherwise. I proposed [lisp-goal].

Comment: Is GOAL-the-language actually available for the general public to use and ask meaningful questions about? It doesn't sound like it was actually released, and the one question tagged for it only uses it as an example of what the OP wants to achieve, not the language they're working in.

Answer (score 13):

*Update: since the burnination process started 2.5 years after posting and this answer reflects the evaluation at the time, it might not be valid anymore.*

I have never heard of them before, but GOAL is actually more than one programming language:

- [GOAL agent programming language](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GOAL_agent_programming_language): [homepage](http://ii.tudelft.nl/trac/goal).
- [Game Oriented Assembly Lisp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Game_Oriented_Assembly_Lisp) (see [Tunaki's answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/317136)).

I would suggest (in no particular order):

- Removing the tag from all questions where it is used abstractly ("I want to achieve...").
- [maven-goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven-goal) and [lisp-goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lisp-goal) might be worth keeping depending on opinions from knowledgeable people.
- [goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goal) will then need a wiki explaining that it is used for the agent programming language. It shouldn't be blacklisted unless someone wants to come up with a tag for the programming language which is not its name.

Comment: As there are currently no questions about the GOAL agent programming language (at least none that I could find), we can't really use it for that. Imo we should burninate it now, and it can get recreated if people actually have questions about the GOAL agent programming language.

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth Well, when burnination starts 2.5 years after the original post things are going to be very different. The answer was valid at the time, probably not anymore for quite some time (as with many super-late burninations, someone might have done it quietly by now).

Answer (score 3):

[goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goal) has been *burninated*.

[image: trogdor]

Thanks to everyone who participated.

## Observations/Retag Guidance:

- The tag can be dropped [from the posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goal+-maven+-maven-2+-maven-3+-maven-plugin+-maven-assembly-plugin+-maven-release-plugin+-maven-surefire-plugin+-maven-jetty-plugin+-maven-archetype+-maven-dependency-plugin+-maven-jaxb2-plugin+-maven-tomcat-plugin+-maven-war-plugin+-maven-shade-plugin+-maven-antrun-plugin+-maven-site-plugin+-maven-failsafe-plugin+-maven-cargo+-maven-profiles+-maven-compiler-plugin) where it is related to [maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/maven).
- The tag [goal-tracking](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goal-tracking) should be used when the post is related to [google-analytics](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/google-analytics). The same can be used for the [3 posts](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/matomo+goal) related to [piwik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/piwik), which is another open source analytics platform.
- The tag can be removed from the 3 questions ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45046979), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39196361), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34897910))related to GoalSeek.
- The tag can be removed from the questions related to Prolog.

(there would be just 4 questions left after all this are done, 1 related to [uml](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/uml) diagrams, 1 related to [lisp-goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/lisp-goal), and 2 others where the tag is not required)

## Progress:

The [goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goal) tag is in the process of being burninated. You can help out by reviewing the questions with this tag, and...

- **editing** questions (to improve the question *and* remove the tag),
- **flagging/closing** questions that are duplicates/off-topic/unclear/too broad/opinion-based,
- filtering on this tag in the [Close Vote Queue](https://stackoverflow.com/review/close/?filter-tags=goal),
- **voting** on questions with this tag,
- voting to **delete** the questions with this tag (after they have been closed, and only if the entire Q&A contains nothing of value). However, keep in mind that at the end of the burnination process all closed questions containing this tag will be deleted automatically. Thus, there's rarely a need to vote to delete these questions.

Here are some quick links to get you started:

- [Open](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoal%5D+closed%3Ano)
- [Closed](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoal%5D+closed%3Ayes)
- [Unanswered](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoal%5D+answers%3A0+closed%3Ano)
- [No Accepted Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoal%5D+hasaccepted%3A0+closed%3Ano)

## Remember that burnination is a *clean-up* effort!

#### Salvage whatever possible by editing and re-tagging.

We don't want to destroy value, so salvaging a post should be your first priority. If a question can be saved, please edit it. Your edit should improve *all* problems with the question *and* remove the [goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goal) tag, possibly replacing it with another tag, as described above in "Observations/Retag Guidance".

#### Unsalvageable questions should just be flagged/closed. They don't need to be retagged.

If the question is not appropriate for this site, then don't worry about removing the [goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goal) tag—just flag/close the question it is attached to.

At the end of the burnination process, all questions that still remain with the [goal](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/goal) tag should have been closed. These will be mass-deleted, which will remove the tag from the system automatically, with minimal disruption.

#### Ask for help if you need it.

If you have any questions about specific questions you come across, or the process in general, please feel free to leave a comment on this post. You can also drop into the [SOCVR chat room](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/41570/so-close-vote-reviewers) for real-time advice and discussion.