# Yet another [application] for burnination

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

The [application] tag was burninated 4 years ago when it was decided to [Burninate the [apps] and [application] tags](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/187403/burninate-the-apps-and-application-tags). However, just a few days back the [application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application) tag has resurfaced, as can be seen [on the New Tags 10k tool](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Stats&daterange=last30days).

The reasoning for burnination of the tag still holds good, from the linked meta post:

> These both seem roughly equivalent to having a tag for [programs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/programs) or [software](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/software) (which was [burninated previously](https://stackoverflow.com/tools?tab=Stats&daterange=last30days)).

---

Going through the 4 criteria for burnination:

> Does it describe the contents of the questions to which it is applied? and is it unambiguous?

It does not unambiguously describe the contents of the question, as just the tag [application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application) does not imply if it is a mobile application, desktop application or if it is a web based application. It might even be related to the various toolkits named "Application".

> Is the concept described even on-topic for the site?

Only programming questions related to applications are on-topic. The posts need to specify the technology in which that application is being programmed to be on-topic. (If it is a general application question, it can be asked on either Super User, Android Enthusiasts or Web Applications) Therefore we can conclude that the tag is not specifically on-topic for the site.

> Does the tag add any meaningful information to the post?

The tag does not add additional information to the post. Rather, we need another tag along with this tag to retrieve some meaningful information.

> Does it mean the same thing in all common contexts?

No, it does not mean the same in all contexts. Most of the posts are either about mobile applications, which require the technology tag instead, or web based applications, which have their own tag [web-application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-application).

---

Can we burninate the tag? There are just 22 questions in the tag at the moment, so if we start early, we can prevent it from growing large.

Comment: Given that this has returned after burnination, perhaps a blacklist request would also be appropriate.

Comment: @Makyen, If it had returned a few weeks or a few months after burnination, I'd totally agree that a blacklist would be more appropriate. However, the tag has returned after 4 years. It goes to show that it's not being actively re-created. If it re-appears again, then we should certainly blacklist it.

Comment: What's the problem with blacklisting, that you (mods) have to reserve it for the cases where the tag is actively recreated?

Comment: Nuke it up, Call of duty's style. Once and for all.

Comment: @user202729 blacklist requires dev/CM intervention. Moderators can not blacklist tags.

Comment: Because this tag has only 25 questions, it qualifies for the abbreviated burnination process, which simply requires buy-in from one 20k user (I don't think anyone can have authoritative knowledge in such a generalist tag). Since we've got that in the form of pnuts' answer below, I'd say let's move this to the next step.

Comment: Boo! This still has a punny title! That's not standard procedure ;-)

Comment: @Cerbrus The no pun rule is applied to only [featured] and [status-planned] posts (and is enforced). We need to keep the love of puns burni[nat]ing in our hearts. :p

Comment: Fair enough, but i'll be [watch]ing you :P

Comment: @Cerbrus I guess you haven't been [watch]ing me https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/284906/revisions :D

Comment: In my defense, I was only barely back from vacation, then. :D

Comment: Hah, you were slacking, @Cerbrus, you gotta do some [movement] https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/260218/the-movement-tag-is-in-the-process-of-being-burninated ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Agreed. And, as you suggest, ASAP is best. And the earlier precedent you mention remains relevant (as you wrote!).

Presently <strike>15, 6, 7, 5, 2 Qs, one of which is Closed</strike> all are deleted.

[application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application) has been *burninated*.

[image]

Comment: it reappeared today :(