# It is time to file another [application] for burnination

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags, burninate-request

I went into detail about how [application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application) was recreated again and again here: [Yet another [application] for burnination](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371416/4099593).

One year later, we're back at the same place:

[image]

[application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/application) has risen to the 2nd position in just a couple of days. I had a quick look at the questions with that tag, and the reasons that [I mentioned an year back still hold true](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/371416/4099593)

Can we burninate the tag again and get a CM to blacklist it this time?  There are 23 questions in that tag as of now.

Comment: Why is that duck looking at the hotchocolate tag?

Comment: It needs some of that sweet hot chocolate @Will.

Comment: This tag has a lot of applications, but none of them are useful on this site. I say we should blacklist it.

Comment: It appears to be burned already.

Comment: Yes, @Luuklag, I went through the posts after this question reached 15 votes. I am waiting for a CM to blacklist it

Comment: Of course, the process is a yearly one -- the burnination is only good for so long before you must re-apply.